# Why can I only delete some answers in flag review screen?

Tags: support, flagging, review-queue

Today I was presented with flag review screen which showed some flags for review.

For some of the posts, I had 2 buttons: "flag" and "delete answer"

But for others, I only had the "flag" button, even though they were flagged as "not an answer".

Why the discrepancy? Was the "delete" button only available after the post accumulates a certain threshold of flags?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "delete" button is only available if you have the right to delete it. As a [trusted-user (+20k)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/privileges/trusted-user) you have the right to vote to delete answers **with score of -1 or lower**.

Comment: Oh. I forgot about the "score <=-1 part" - good catch!